# Is "epitomize" somewhat presumptuous when used to describe my own work?

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to say that my current work is a great example to illustrate the use of algorithm X in the filed of medicine. The main point that I'd like to address is not that my current work is awesome, but that algorithm X is very awesome and has facilitated many medicine works, such as mine.

Given what I am trying to express, can I say

> My current work epitomizes the great applications of algorithm X in the medicine field.

Does this sound presumptuous and deviate from what I actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You example sentence is saying this:

> My current work is the prototypical (the best) example of the use of algorithm X.

If you want the focus of the sentence to be how algorithm X is awesome in the medical field you should change the order of the sentence to be more like this:

> The applications of algorithm X has facilitated many innovations in the medical field, as can be seen in my current work.

If you want a slightly fancies way of saying "seen" to match the character of the language of your piece you could use:

- Evidenced
- Demonstrated
- Illustrated
- Validated (may be too close to a term of art in the medical field if that is what the paper is for)
- Exhibited
- Modeled

As an aside, if you mean the the arena of helping people's medical issues you should use medical field instead of medicine field.  If you mean the field of drugs (prescription usually but could be used for both prescription and none) it should be pharmaceutical field.

Comment: **Typifies** is another possibility.

Comment: So it's not just somewhat presumptuous.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the phrase *prime example* or *demonstration* to get your meaning across in a better way. However, it is not so much your use of the word *epitomises* as the way you phrase the rest of your sentence:

I believe that my current work is a prime example of the great ways in which algorithm X can be applied to the field of medicine.

I believe that my current work is a demonstration of the great ways in which algorithm X can be applied to the field of medicine.

The latter might be used if you want to lessen the focus on your work and place it more on the algorithm. Your current sentence seems to suggest that your work is the best use of algorithm X to date, which I don't think is what you wanted to get across.

Answer (score 0):

**Original answer:**

How about:

> The extreme (increased?) accuracy shown in current medical works (experiments?),
>   including my own, has been (is?) made possible by Algorithm X.

or (If your prefer to avoid the passive voice):

> Algorithm X has made (makes?) possible the extreme/increased accuracy shown in
>   current medical works/experiments, including my own.

**Edited to add the following:**

> Yes, I interpret your version as at least somewhat presumptuous and I
>   think it deviates at least somewhat from what I think you actually
>   want to say.

If, as I believe, you're trying to go from somewhat to not-at-all presumptuous (or perhaps even humble-sounding) I would consider my un-edited, first answer above, but please consider the following if you're looking to go to full-blown, super presumptuous (which I know you're not and I offer it as a joke):

> The genius of my use of Algorithm X in my current work is surpassed
>   only by that of the algorithm itself.

Other answers already given (and those to come will) fall somewhere between my real answer and my joke answer and are probably closer to what you actually want to say.